# AS3: How to supplement function calls in an existing library?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a semi-newbie question.  I've been programming for years, but all my early experience was pre-OOP and my brain kind of settled that way.  I'm also new to Actionscript.  So hopefully this is an easy one for somebody.

I'm using as3svgrendererlib to import SVG.  It works great, but I need to be able to serialize the graphics it outputs.  But I can't serialize sprites, so I have to go all the way down to the IGraphicsData level to get something that I can.  But the library doesn't give me that data.  It only gives me sprites.  So I need to change that.

Since there are only a handful of drawing methods that it ultimately uses (`beginFill`, `drawRect`, etc), my thinking is that if I can hook into those and supplement them with my own code to output IGraphicsData as well, then I'll be in business.  Now I know I could do that by using "extends" classes, but that would require substantial modification of the library to change all of those standard calls to my custom ones.

So I'm wondering: Is there a magic OOP way to write methods that will universally intercept calls to existing methods without needing to modify the original calls?

Thanks!  :)

EDIT: I need resolution-independence, so it's important that I keep the graphics in vector and not convert them to bitmap.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I was going to suggest modifying the library's source, but it seems like it's not available. Maybe there is an alternative open-source library?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this kind of thing in OOP, you either need to override the class (but that might not be possible in your case) or modify the library directly.

However, in your case, a possible solution would be to:

1. Draw the SVG to a sprite using the library.
2. Draw the sprite to a `BitmapData`.
3. Finally, get the pixel data using `getPixels()` and serialize it.

Something like this should work;

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

// Add the child to the stage...
// Draw the SVG to the sprite...

var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
bmpData.draw(sprite);

var pixelData:ByteArray = bmpData.getPixels(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpData.width, bmpData.height));

// Here serialize the byte array
```

In this example, note that spriteWidth/spriteHeight are not necessarily "sprite.width" and "sprite.height" (sprites often report dimensions different from what you would expect). So you need to decide in advance the size of the rendered SVG and use this when building the `BitmapData`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that I need to keep the graphics in vector.  I'm writing for mobile devices, so the difference in resolution between an older phone and a newer tablet makes bitmaps a real pain to work with.

Comment: Why? The device using them would be the device writing them, right?

Comment: @TrickyWidget, my understanding is that you need to convert the SVG to another format. So which format would that be? I would think SVG is already a very good format for vector graphics so why not keep that?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship If I went with bitmaps, I'd have to either package them large enough to look good on tablets, which would be absurdly huge for phones, or size them for phones and then they'd look terrible on tablets.

Comment: @Laurent I want something that loads and renders quickly within AS3, which SVG does not.  The best I've been able to find so far is to serialize native IGraphicsData.  But I'd be open to other options, so long as it works well (and can hopefully be able to import from SVG).